# IB design controls of UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview, uiscrollview

I have a UIViewController in it a UIView.
I wish to create the following design in IB: place a UIScrollView(Gray area) that will take 3/4 of the UIView (Blue area)

[image]

in the designer I have more controls than the gray area (scrollView) can hold using the space it takes on screen (the yellow and red controls)

[image]

I was wondering how can I place the yellow and red controls in IB to be part of the scrollView & when running the app make the scrollView actually scroll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Increase the scrollview to a size that will house all elements (including red and yellow labels), add the labels as children (drag and drop inside the scrollview) and shrink the scrollview to the desired height. In code, use `[SCROLLVIEW setContentSize:CGSizeMake(width,height)]` to enable the scroll.

Assuming you have a reference to the red label in your code, you could do something like this

`float contentHeight = RED_LABEL.frame.origin.y + RED_LABEL.frame.size.height;
[SCROLL_VIEW setContentSize:CGSizeMake(SCROLL_VIEW.contentSize.width, contentHeight];`

Hope this helps.